# How to find critical values for a two sample t test

Tags: statistics

How do you find the critical values for a non-pooled two sample t-distribution test? I've been searching for online notes and I've gotten the following formula: $cv=\pm t_{1-\alpha,d}$. But I'm unsure how to use this formula with my current data set. I have $\alpha=.01$ and $d\approx8.579142813$ so $cv=\pm t_{.9,8.579142813}$. What would these critical values be and could you give an explanation of how you got the value? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the question is : what is the value of $±t_{.9,8.579142813}$?.

If this is your question then note that $d$ should be an integer. If after computation it comes not a integer then approximate it by an integer. Here in your case $d$=9. Then we need the value of $±t_{.9,9}$. This value can be obtained by the standard $t$-Table. [Here](http://www.socr.ucla.edu/applets.dir/t-table.html) is a copy of table. The value is -1.383.